# Mixing Hamcrest and TestNG

Tags: java, testng, hamcrest

Has anyone integrated Hamcrest with TestNG so that its matchers can easily be used in TestNG assertions?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In short, to answer your question: You don't need to integrate TestNG with Hamcrest.  Just call `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(...)` directly which throws `java.lang.AssertionError`.

**Background**

I found your question via Google, wondering exactly the same issue.  After further Googling, I didn't find any satisfying answers, so I read the source code for JUnit's integration with Hamcrest.

With JUnit, Hamcrest integration is normally used by calling:

```
org.junit.Assert.assertThat(
    T actual,
    org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super T> matcher)
```

When I read the source code, I discovered it just a small wrapper to call:

```
org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(
    String reason,
    T actual,
    org.hamcest.Matcher<? super T> matcher)
```

This function throws `java.lang.AssertionError`.

Comment: This is great except that _TestNG_ has [soft assertions](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.21/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html) which can't be used from _Hamcrest_.

Comment: @Bass There's a workaround for [soft assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52151089/tetsng-softassert-with-hamcrest-matcher)

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing problem with empty method then I would suggest to add `hamcrest` first in dependency list. or import first `hamcrest`, it will solve the problem.

I was using TestNJ with rexsl(internally using Hamcrest) and it fails to find empty method.
then I added rexsl first in dependency list, if you are adding library in class path you can try to add first the Hamcrest one.

hope it will help someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
 1. http://search.maven.org/

2. Search for 'java-hamcrest' the latest as for now is '2.0.0.0'
3. find dependency for Gradle (in my case)
4. Added compile 'org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0' to build.gradle in my project.