# Testing two JSON objects for equality ignoring child order in Java

Tags: java, json, junit

I'm looking for a JSON parsing library that supports comparing two JSON objects ignoring child order, specifically for unit testing JSON returning from a web service.

Do any of the major JSON libraries support this? The org.json library simply does a reference comparison.

Comment: Can't serialize both objects to string representation and compare? I guess all of the libraries support `toString()` to convert the object to `JSON` string.

Comment: That assumes that order on serialization to and from strings are always the same.  I'm not comfortable making that assumption.

Comment: You're right Jeff, it's not safe at all. This test shows a scenario where the mappings are the same but toString() does not return the same output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5974797. This is because the underlying HashMap can grow, and if you remove keys, the HashMap internal array does not shrink.

Comment: Json Compare [json-compare](https://github.com/fslev/json-compare)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

As a general architectural point, I usually advise against letting dependencies on a particular serialization format bleed out beyond your storage/networking layer; thus, I'd first recommend that you consider testing equality between your own application objects rather than their JSON manifestations.

Having said that, I'm currently a big fan of [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) which my quick read of their [ObjectNode.equals()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html) implementation suggests does the set membership comparison that you want:

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (o.getClass() != getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    ObjectNode other = (ObjectNode) o;
    if (other.size() != size()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (_children != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> en : _children.entrySet()) {
            String key = en.getKey();
            JsonNode value = en.getValue();

            JsonNode otherValue = other.get(key);

            if (otherValue == null || !otherValue.equals(value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This method is not symmetric, as it only tests 'subset' relationship of the children, not equality. the 'other' object may have more children then in _children, and this method would still return true.

Comment: @Yoni: Not true, as there's a size comparison.  They must have the exact same number of children as well as the same children.


@Jolly Roger: In this case, I'm not serializing the object from JSON back into a POJO, but when sending JSON a system that does, I can't rely on it sending it back in the exact same format in which I sent it.

Comment: @Jeff Did this work for you? In junit, assertEquals fails for me. The project is using an old version (1.5), fyi.

Comment: I think you're missing some high level testing if you aren't asserting JSON.  You could have a thin test which makes a http request and responds with some expected JSON - it's the main functional behaviour of the web service.

Comment: Just a minor note regarding performance: the code that compares 'value' with 'otherValue' can be simplified to 
if (value.equals(other.get(key)) 
   return false;
as 'value' is guaranteed to be not-null and JsonNode's equals() method ought to accept a null argument.

Answer (score 195):

Try Skyscreamer's [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert).

Its *non-strict* mode has two major advantages that make it less brittle:

- Object extensibility (e.g. With an expected value of *{id:1}*, this would still pass: *{id:1,moredata:'x'}*.)
- Loose array ordering (e.g. ['dog','cat']==['cat','dog'])

In strict mode it behaves more like json-lib's test class.

A test looks something like this:

```
@Test
public void testGetFriends() {
    JSONObject data = getRESTData("/friends/367.json");
    String expected = "{friends:[{id:123,name:\"Corby Page\"}"
        + ",{id:456,name:\"Solomon Duskis\"}]}";
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, data, false);
}
```

The parameters in the JSONAssert.assertEquals() call are *expectedJSONString*, *actualDataString*, and *isStrict*.

The result messages are pretty clear, which is important when comparing really big JSON objects.

Comment: I've been using this solution, but I've just found that you could also provide a JSONCompareMode of you choosing. One of which is NON_EXTENSIBLE. So you'd have something like this: 
`JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, data, JSONCompareMode.NON_EXTENSIBLE);` The NON_EXTENSIBLE mode means that any new or missing fields cause failures, but the order doesn't. Using false would instigate lenient mode which wouldn't report any extra or missing child elements.

Comment: The NON_EXTENSIBLE compare mode is *exactly* what I was looking for. Thanks for this, Dan.

Comment: Before I get all excited: does this support nested JSON objects and arrays as well? :)

Comment: First of all , JSONAssert works great in most of the cases:).
However, in the case of arrays in json elements,  the error message does not look very explanatory.Looks like some error messages can be improved.Is that being considered?
Is this project still active?

Comment: It's still active, though largely in maintenance mode.  If someone offers a pull request to improve the error messages, I'm happy to review it.

Comment: People might want to take [this JSONassert issue](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert/issues/44) into account before using the library: it indicates that there are currently potential licensing issues with a dependency of the library.

Comment: What is the method "getRESTData"?

Comment: JSONAssert issue #44 fixed with clean-room library replacement in PR 67, released today as JSONAssert 1.4.0.

Comment: I'd like to mention [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) as an alternative to JSONAssert - and it is specialized for testing REST-API responses. (disclaimer: am dev).

Comment: Error: Cannot resolve method 'getRESTData'. How can I resolve this issue, please?

Comment: Abandonware. Did not work and tried emailing them. `The following message to <jsonassert-dev@skyscreamer.org> was undeliverable.
The reason for the problem:
5.1.0 - Unknown address error 550-"5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. `

Answer (score 62):

Using GSON

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement o1 = parser.parse("{a : {a : 2}, b : 2}");
JsonElement o2 = parser.parse("{b : 2, a : {a : 2}}");
assertEquals(o1, o2);
```

Edit: Since [GSON v2.8.6](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-286) the instance method `JsonParser.parse` is deprecated. You have to use the static method `JsonParser.parseString`:

```
JsonElement o1 = JsonParser.parseString("{a : {a : 2}, b : 2}");
JsonElement o2 = JsonParser.parseString("{b : 2, a : {a : 2}}");
assertEquals(o1, o2);
```

Comment: Works in GSON 2.8.2 for me.

Comment: it is not working if jsonArray elements are not in order. version 2.8.2

Comment: Not Working for me if the order of object/element is different

Comment: It worked for me because I just wanted it for a unit test where the two jsons properties had the same order

Comment: @GabrielBB You should edit the question and indicate what version the API is deprecated in, and in what version the new style of code starts to work.

Comment: @GabrialBB, I approved your previous edit as a reviewer working on the suggested edits queue. I'm sure your new answer will get approved by whoever's voting on it when it comes up in the queue again. Thanks.

Answer (score 43):

I would do the following,

```
JSONObject obj1 = /*json*/;
JSONObject obj2 = /*json*/;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(obj1.toString());
JsonNode tree2 = mapper.readTree(obj2.toString());

return tree1.equals(tree2);
```

Comment: If you're using Jackson already this is the best answer IMHO.

Comment: but this is an strict comparison I think. It will return false for two equal json having different order of elements.

Comment: @deadpool the principle is sound, you'd just need to change the comparison to be more involved (checking for key fields for example rather than a simple equals of the trees).

Comment: This is the best answer ever. Not only it answers my question now, as it also answers almost every object comparison we need to do. thanks, joshu.

Comment: @deadpool, it may have been a strict comparison, but it is not strict now.

Comment: This don't work when you have array as nested object and there is difference in order in array

Comment: This will ignore most order changes except for list order changes that must be the same. see here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects

Comment: in `jackson:2.14.2` order is important. see `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode.equals`

Answer (score 23):

Use this library: https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit

Pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-unit-assertj</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

IGNORING_ARRAY_ORDER - ignores order in arrays

```java
assertThatJson("{\"test\":[1,2,3]}")
  .when(Option.IGNORING_ARRAY_ORDER)
  .isEqualTo("{\"test\": [3,2,1]}");
```

Comment: can you add more comment how we can use it i add it to my pom but we need doc in order to understand how to use it

Comment: sure usage is very simple:     
Add this to your pom.

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-unit</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: 10x i have looked at the instruction at the link and i found it :)

Answer (score 20):

You could try using json-lib's [JSONAssert](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/test/JSONAssert.html) class:

```java
JSONAssert.assertEquals(
  "{foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux'}",
  JSONObject.fromObject("{foo: 'bar', baz: 'xyzzy'}")
);
```

Gives:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: objects differed at key [baz]; expected:<[qux]> but was:<[xyzzy]>
```

Comment: Or even simpler: JSONAssert.assertJsonEquals(
  "{foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux'}", {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xyzzy'}");

Comment: Whil this solution works for the order of data items within the JSON, it will fail if the order of elements within arrays does not match. If your code uses a Set that is converted to JSON for example.

The following JSON compare would fail:
`JSONAssert.assertJsonEquals( "{foo: 'bar', list: [{test: '1'}, {rest: '2'}] }", "{ foo: 'bar', list: [{rest: '2'}, {test: '1'}] }");`


With the message:
`junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: : : objects differed at key [list];: arrays first differed at element [0];: objects differed at key [test];`

Comment: Yes, this is a limitation of Json :(.  json.org shows that there is no unordered collection token.  { } can only surround key-value pairs.  This is highly irritating

Answer (score 14):

If you are already using JUnit, the latest version now employs Hamcrest.  It is a generic matching framework (especially useful for unit testing) that can be extended to build new matchers.

There is a small open source library called `hamcrest-json` with JSON-aware matches.  It is well documented, tested, and supported.  Below are some useful links:

- [Source code](https://github.com/hertzsprung/hamcrest-json)
- [Home page](http://www.datumedge.co.uk/hamcrest-json/)
- [Javadocs for main matcher](http://www.datumedge.co.uk/hamcrest-json/apidocs/reference/uk/co/datumedge/hamcrest/json/SameJSONAs.html):

Example code using objects from the JSON library `org.json.simple`:

```
Assert.assertThat(
    jsonObject1.toJSONString(),
    SameJSONAs.sameJSONAs(jsonObject2.toJSONString()));
```

Optionally, you may (1) allow "any-order" arrays and (2) ignore extra fields.

Since there are a variety of JSON libraries for Java (`Jackson`, `GSON`, `json-lib`, etc.), it is useful that `hamcrest-json` supports JSON text (as `java.lang.String`), as well as natively supporting objects from Douglas Crockford's JSON library `org.json`.

Finally, if you are not using JUnit, you can use Hamcrest directly for assertions.  ([I wrote about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092996/mixing-hamcrest-and-testng/16494477#16494477))

Comment: What is the advantage of using hamcrast matchers instead of using the JSONAssert directly?

Comment: @Johannes: Style only.

Comment: The hamcrest-json sources currently have a last commit date of 2012.  It may not be so well supported anymore.

Answer (score 13):

You can try [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit). It can compare two JSON objects and report differences. It's built on top of Jackson.

For example

```
assertThatJson("{\"test\":1}").isEqualTo("{\n\"test\": 2\n}");
```

Results in

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON documents are different:
Different value found in node "test". Expected 1, got 2.
```

Answer (score 8):

One thing I did and it works wonders is to read both objects into HashMap and then compare with a regular assertEquals(). It will call the equals() method of the hashmaps, which will recursively compare all objects inside (they will be either other hashmaps or some single value object like a string or integer). This was done using Codehaus' Jackson JSON parser.

```
assertEquals(mapper.readValue(expectedJson, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}), mapper.readValue(actualJson, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}));
```

A similar approach can be used if the JSON object is an array instead.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using this, and works fine for me (with org.json.*):

```
package com.project1.helpers;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class JSONUtils {

    public static boolean areEqual(Object ob1, Object ob2) throws JSONException {
        Object obj1Converted = convertJsonElement(ob1);
        Object obj2Converted = convertJsonElement(ob2);
        return obj1Converted.equals(obj2Converted);
    }

    private static Object convertJsonElement(Object elem) throws JSONException {
        if (elem instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) elem;
            Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
            Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                jsonMap.put(key, convertJsonElement(obj.get(key)));
            }
            return jsonMap;
        } else if (elem instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) elem;
            Set<Object> jsonSet = new HashSet<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                jsonSet.add(convertJsonElement(arr.get(i)));
            }
            return jsonSet;
        } else {
            return elem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method just compares the objects, but doesn't give a reasonable explanation what the difference is.

Answer (score 4):

For org.json I've rolled out my own solution, a method that compares to JSONObject instances. I didn't work with complex JSON objects in that project, so I don't know whether this works in all scenarios. Also, given that I use this in unit tests, I didn't put effort into optimizations. Here it is:

```
public static boolean jsonObjsAreEqual (JSONObject js1, JSONObject js2) throws JSONException {
    if (js1 == null || js2 == null) {
        return (js1 == js2);
    }

    List<String> l1 =  Arrays.asList(JSONObject.getNames(js1));
    Collections.sort(l1);
    List<String> l2 =  Arrays.asList(JSONObject.getNames(js2));
    Collections.sort(l2);
    if (!l1.equals(l2)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String key : l1) {
        Object val1 = js1.get(key);
        Object val2 = js2.get(key);
        if (val1 instanceof JSONObject) {
            if (!(val2 instanceof JSONObject)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!jsonObjsAreEqual((JSONObject)val1, (JSONObject)val2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (val1 == null) {
            if (val2 != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }  else if (!val1.equals(val2)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since you mentioned optimizations :), if `val1` is null you will get a NullPointerException from this code `if (!val1.equals(val2)) {`

Comment: It happens to the best of us also :). +1 for fixing it in your answer.

Comment: point taken :) Hope that it doesn't get too much votes though, otherwise it's gonna be lots of support.

Comment: You did not consider if `js2` is `null` or not when `js1` is not `null`

Comment: This code does not work for nested objects/sequences.

Comment: I have nested objects and I simply added one more check `else if (!(val1 instanceof JSONObject) && !val1.equals(val2)) {
                return false;
            }`. Not really good but works for me.

Answer (score 3):

For those like me wanting to do this with Jackson, you can use [json-unit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit).

```
JsonAssert.assertJsonEquals(jsonNode1, jsonNode2);
```

The errors give useful feedback on the type of mismatch:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON documents have different values:
Different value found in node "heading.content[0].tag[0]". Expected 10209, got 10206.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [zjsonpatch](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch) library, which presents the diff information in accordance with RFC 6902 (JSON Patch). Its very easy to use. Please visit its description page for its usage

Answer (score 3):

I know it is usually considered only for testing but you could use the Hamcrest JSON *comparitorSameJSONAs* in Hamcrest JSON.

[Hamcrest JSON SameJSONAs](http://www.datumedge.co.uk/hamcrest-json/apidocs/reference/uk/co/datumedge/hamcrest/json/SameJSONAs.html)

Answer (score 3):

For comparing jsons I recommend using my library, JSONCompare:
https://github.com/fslev/json-compare

```
// Compare by regex
String expected = "{\"a\":\".*me.*\"}";
String actual = "{\"a\":\"some text\"}";
JSONCompare.assertEquals(expected, actual);  // True

// Check expected array has no extra elements
String expected = "[1,\"test\",4,\"!.*\"]";
String actual = "[4,1,\"test\"]";
JSONCompare.assertEquals(expected, actual);  // True

// Check expected array has no numbers
String expected = "[\"\\\\\\d+\"]";
String actual = "[\"text\",\"test\"]";
JSONCompare.assertEquals(expected, actual);  // True

// Check expected array has no numbers
String expected = "[\"\\\\\\d+\"]";
String actual = "[2018]";
JSONCompare.assertNotEquals(expected, actual);  // True
```

Answer (score 3):

> Do any of the major JSON libraries support this? The org.json library simply does a reference comparison.

But `org.json` *does* support this! Use [`similar()`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#similar-java.lang.Object-) instead of `equals()`.

Answer (score 3):

This may help those working with **Spring Framework**. You may reuse what is used internally for doing assertions on **ResultActions** (for controller testing):

*Import: org.springframework.test.util.JsonExpectationsHelper*

And you can write tests that break with verbose output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: someObject.someArray[1].someInternalObject2.value
Expected: 456
     got: 4567
```

Test code:

```
@Test
void test() throws Exception {

    final String json1 =
        "{" +
        "  'someObject': {" +
        "    'someArray': [" +
        "      {" +
        "        'someInternalObject': {" +
        "          'value': '123'" +
        "        }" +
        "      }," +
        "      {" +
        "        'someInternalObject2': {" +
        "          'value': '456'" +
        "        }" +
        "      }" +
        "    ]" +
        "  }" +
        "}";

    final String json2 =
        "{" +
        "  'someObject': {" +
        "    'someArray': [" +
        "      {" +
        "        'someInternalObject': {" +
        "          'value': '123'" +
        "        }" +
        "      }," +
        "      {" +
        "        'someInternalObject2': {" +
        "          'value': '4567'" +
        "        }" +
        "      }" +
        "    ]" +
        "  }" +
        "}";

    new JsonExpectationsHelper().assertJsonEqual(json1, json2, true);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Direct usage of [JSONassert](https://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/) library was disallowed by my management. However, JsonExpectationsHelper uses it :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd take the library at http://json.org/java/, and modify the `equals` method of JSONObject and JSONArray to do a deep equality test. To make sure that it works regradless of the order of the children, all you need to do is replace the inner map with a `TreeMap`, or use something like `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: its not that great - it really should have come with code to do json comparison.

Comment: But imagine writing that code where JSON can be anything in any structure...write the compare on that!  Its like writing a compare for all types HTML pages.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static boolean jsonsEqual(Object obj1, Object obj2) throws JSONException

    {
        if (!obj1.getClass().equals(obj2.getClass()))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (obj1 instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObj1 = (JSONObject) obj1;

            JSONObject jsonObj2 = (JSONObject) obj2;

            String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj1);
            String[] names2 = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObj1);
            if (names.length != names2.length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (String fieldName:names)
            {
                Object obj1FieldValue = jsonObj1.get(fieldName);

                Object obj2FieldValue = jsonObj2.get(fieldName);

                if (!jsonsEqual(obj1FieldValue, obj2FieldValue))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (obj1 instanceof JSONArray)
        {
            JSONArray obj1Array = (JSONArray) obj1;
            JSONArray obj2Array = (JSONArray) obj2;

            if (obj1Array.length() != obj2Array.length())
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < obj1Array.length(); i++)
            {
                boolean matchFound = false;

                for (int j = 0; j < obj2Array.length(); j++)
                {
                    if (jsonsEqual(obj1Array.get(i), obj2Array.get(j)))
                    {
                        matchFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!matchFound)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!obj1.equals(obj2))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: within jsonArrays this returns true if *some* of the elements coincide, as opposed to *all* the elements coincide.

Comment: @matiasg - does the `if (obj1Array.length() != obj2Array.length())` not ensure *all* elements coincide?

Comment: @kwah: nope. Consider this example: obj1Array = [1,1,1], obj2Array = [1,2,3]. This would return true. Also, even if elements coincide, they should be in the same order. This would return true for [1,2,3] and [2,3,1] too, which is wrong

Answer (score 2):

[Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) is exactly what you are looking for. Here is an example:

```
* def myJson = { foo: 'world', hey: 'ho', zee: [5], cat: { name: 'Billie' } }
* match myJson = { cat: { name: 'Billie' }, hey: 'ho', foo: 'world', zee: [5] }
```

(disclaimer: dev here)

Answer (score 2):

What I did is converting the jsons into maps using gson and comparing the maps using assertj:

```
Map<Object, Object> resMap = gson.fromJson(res, new TypeToken<Map<Object, Object>>() {}.getType());
Map<Object, Object> expectedMap = gson.fromJson(expected, new TypeToken<Map<Object, Object>>() {}.getType());
Assertions.assertThat(resMap).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expectedMap);
```

The result is a nice comparison between all attributes, recursively!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code using Jackson ObjectMapper. To know more read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.*

boolean compareJsonPojo(Object pojo1, Object pojo2) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String str1 = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo1);
            String str2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo2);
            return mapper.readTree(str1).equals(mapper.readTree(str2));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Error comparing JSON objects: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing else seemed to work quite right, so I wrote this:

```
private boolean jsonEquals(JsonNode actualJson, JsonNode expectJson) {
    if(actualJson.getNodeType() != expectJson.getNodeType()) return false;

    switch(expectJson.getNodeType()) {
    case NUMBER:
        return actualJson.asDouble() == expectJson.asDouble();
    case STRING:
    case BOOLEAN:
        return actualJson.asText().equals(expectJson.asText());
    case OBJECT:
        if(actualJson.size() != expectJson.size()) return false;

        Iterator<String> fieldIterator = actualJson.fieldNames();
        while(fieldIterator.hasNext()) {
            String fieldName = fieldIterator.next();
            if(!jsonEquals(actualJson.get(fieldName), expectJson.get(fieldName))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        break;
    case ARRAY:
        if(actualJson.size() != expectJson.size()) return false;
        List<JsonNode> remaining = new ArrayList<>();
        expectJson.forEach(remaining::add);
        // O(N^2)   
        for(int i=0; i < actualJson.size(); ++i) {
            boolean oneEquals = false;
            for(int j=0; j < remaining.size(); ++j) {
                if(jsonEquals(actualJson.get(i), remaining.get(j))) {
                    oneEquals = true;
                    remaining.remove(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!oneEquals) return false;
        }
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be more helpful to compare two JsonObject, JsonArray, JsonPrimitive and JasonElements.

```
private boolean compareJson(JsonElement json1, JsonElement json2) {
        boolean isEqual = true;
        // Check whether both jsonElement are not null
        if (json1 != null && json2 != null) {

            // Check whether both jsonElement are objects
            if (json1.isJsonObject() && json2.isJsonObject()) {
                Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> ens1 = ((JsonObject) json1).entrySet();
                Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> ens2 = ((JsonObject) json2).entrySet();
                JsonObject json2obj = (JsonObject) json2;
                if (ens1 != null && ens2 != null) {
                    // (ens2.size() == ens1.size())
                    // Iterate JSON Elements with Key values
                    for (Entry<String, JsonElement> en : ens1) {
                        isEqual = isEqual && compareJson(en.getValue(), json2obj.get(en.getKey()));
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // Check whether both jsonElement are arrays
            else if (json1.isJsonArray() && json2.isJsonArray()) {
                JsonArray jarr1 = json1.getAsJsonArray();
                JsonArray jarr2 = json2.getAsJsonArray();
                if (jarr1.size() != jarr2.size()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    int i = 0;
                    // Iterate JSON Array to JSON Elements
                    for (JsonElement je : jarr1) {
                        isEqual = isEqual && compareJson(je, jarr2.get(i));
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Check whether both jsonElement are null
            else if (json1.isJsonNull() && json2.isJsonNull()) {
                return true;
            }

            // Check whether both jsonElement are primitives
            else if (json1.isJsonPrimitive() && json2.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                if (json1.equals(json2)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (json1 == null && json2 == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return isEqual;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.areEqual(json1, json2); //using BlobCity Java Commons
```

https://tech.blobcity.com/2018/09/02/json-equals-in-java-to-compare-two-jsons

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers, I tried JSONAssert but it failed. So I used Jackson with zjsonpatch. I posted details in the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62088365/398348).

Answer (score 0):

`toMap()` in `JSONObject` works fine with nested objects and arrays already.

As the java.util.Map interface specifies to check the mappings and not the order, comparing the Maps is fine and also recursive.

```
json1 = new JSONObject("{...}");
json2 = new JSONObject("{...}");
json1.toMap().equals(json2.toMap());
```

It will work fine with any order and nested elements.

It will *NOT* however work with extra/ignored elements. If those are known you can remove them before calling `equals` on the maps.

Answer (score 0):

ModelAssert - https://github.com/webcompere/model-assert does this. By default, it prefers the JSON to be in order, but it can use relaxed order of object keys and array elements:

```java
assertJson(json1)
   .where().keysInAnyOrder().arrayInAnyOrder()
   .isEqualTo(json2);
```

This assertion is *AssertJ style* - i.e. using a fluent DSL. ModelAssert can also be used to build Hamcrest or Mockito matchers with the same DSL.

The Json can be a `String`, `File`, Jackson `JsonNode`, or even a POJO that is spontaneously converted to JSON for comparison.

There's also support for yml.