# Stable/Terministic comparison of JSON objects in Jackson and GSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

As it turns out Jackson [does not do stable](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5974797) JSON object comparison contrary to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/compare-two-json-objects-in-java). So I was wondering if GSON has stable comparison of JSON objects. (without having to override equals/implement one's own comparator)

Answer (score 2):

Your gist shows org.json code, not [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind).

Jackson has a perfectly able .equals() implementation for all `JsonNode`s. And that includes all "non container types" as well as "container types":

```
final JsonNodeFactory factory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;

final JsonNode node1 = factory.objectNode().put("hello", "world");
final JsonNode node2 = factory.objectNode().put("hello", "world");

node1.equals(node2); // true
```

Of course, it does respect JSON's "order does not matter" with object members: `{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }` is equal to `{ "b": 2, "a": 1 }` -- as it should.

---

That may only be my opinion as well, but really, when it comes to JSON, *anything* is better than org.json.

Comment: plus[1] for the order doesnt matter mention!