# Compare JSON with nested arrays and jsons (Array order does not matter)

Tags: java, arrays, json

Hello I'm trying to compare two json in java, each key can contain a json object or array of json objects, and each one of them can also be an array or json.

Here is an example of the Json:

```
{
  "id": "123123asd123",
  "attributes": [
      {
         "name": "apps",
         "values": [
             "111",
             "222"
             ]
      },
      {
         "name": "city",
         "values": [
              "NY"
              ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to get two json from this kind and compare them without caring about the order of the arrays.
As you can see the key 'attributes is an array of json so if i have another json like the one up here and the element in the array with key city is before apps i want the test to pass.
aswell of the numbers inside the apps values i dont care if it is 111,222 or 222,111

If anyone know any external java lib that is doing that ill be happy hear.
Or any idea how to implement this compare manually? or even an idea that will this kind of json and reorganize it so it will be easy to compare share that with me.

Comment: You can use org.json [http://www.json.org/java/index.html] to parse the JSON string and create your own objects containing name and array of values and use it or compare it as you like.

Comment: JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a data format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750

Comment: Use Google Gson to unmarshal this JSON into object. Then you are free to write logic to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library she is cool i'm using it all the day for my Webservice Test:

https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"id\": \"123123asd123\",\n" +
            "  \"attributes\": [\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "         \"name\": \"apps\",\n" +
            "         \"values\": [\n" +
            "             \"111\",\n" +
            "             \"222\"\n" +
            "             ]\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "         \"name\": \"city\",\n" +
            "         \"values\": [\n" +
            "              \"NY\"\n" +
            "              ]\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";

    List<String> names = JsonPath.read(json, "$.attributes[*].name");
    for(String name : names) {
        //TODO assert that name is in other list from other json
    }
```