# In java how to compare two json objects having only one field

Tags: java

How to compare two json documents? The first json object is `{id=20:F4:1B:91:AF:73}`
and the second one is also having the same list of such json object so how to compare this.

Comment: [Compare two JSON objects in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/compare-two-json-objects-in-java) ?

Comment: Not that much difficult. What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating it,the problem is when i retreiving json object from solr the SolrDocument is coming in infront of my json object,this text is creating problem SolrDocument{id=20:F4:1B:91:AF:73} because of this i cann't convert it into string .If you know somthing it will be a great help for me.

Comment: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
 at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433) This error is commig when i am paasing my json object in JSONObject constructor.

Comment: i solved it thanks for replying