# java org.json compare object

Tags: java, json, xml, org.json, jsonassert

I'm using [`org.json`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) to convert XML to JSON and I want to unit test (using `JUnit`) my parsing process.
However, when I try to compare the objects using `json.equals` it fails. I understand that `jackson` has implemented the `equals` method properly. Is there a way to unit test the equality of the objects with `org.json`?

```
...
JSONObject actual = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
JSONObject expected = new JSONObject().put("key","val");
assertEquals(expected, actual); // false
assertEquals(expected.toString(), actual.toString()) // true
```

Comment: take a look at this question, maybe some of the answers can give you hints on how to resolve your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/compare-two-json-objects-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JSONassert, avialable at github https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using ModelAssert - https://github.com/webcompere/model-assert - this would look like so:

```java
JSONObject actual = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
JSONObject expected = new JSONObject().put("key","val");
assertJson(actual)
   .isEqualTo(expected);
```

However, there's a chance that things such as key order may be affected by the conversion to `JSONObject`. In that case you can relax key order:

```java
assertJson(actual)
   .where().keysInAnyOrder()
   .isEqualTo(expected);
```