# how to check if two json objects are equal in java?

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have two large nested `json objects` which I need to compare for equality.

I followed the following steps but failed.

1. I converted the json objects into treemaps and json arrays into hashsets and finally returned a treemap for each.
2. I used equals method of map to compare for equality.
3. Though both the maps are sorted(treemaps) and exactly equal in key,value pairs,the comparision is resulting in not equal
   Can anyone suggest a good solution for this and the reason why the case is failing?

Comment: Can you show some code? Which library are you using?

Comment: can you provide a sample of json array let me know how nested is it?

Comment: Thanks to all for your response. I solved it by converting the final thing to String and comparing both the strings. As both are in sorted order it worked.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer here: [Compare two JSON objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/compare-two-json-objects-in-java)

Covers the same thing. There's a number of ways, but I suggestion Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Thanks to all for your response. I solved it by converting the final thing to String and comparing both the strings. As both are in sorted order it worked.

Answer (score 1):

To Check instantly,

try
http://jsondiff.com/

For programmatic approach

provide a sample of your JSON Data and code.

Comment: Thanks to all for your response. I solved it by converting the final thing to String and comparing both the strings. As both are in sorted order it worked.

Comment: @PriyaMounica , cheers , It is  always best  when you solve it on your own!!