# Ignore specific attributes when comparing two json files

Tags: java, json, groovy, jsonassert

I have been successfully using JSONAssert to compare two json responses like this:

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(response2.getResponseBodyContent(), response1.getResponseBodyContent(), JSONCompareMode.LENIENT)
```

I now need to ignore certain attributes as described here:

[Ignore specific nodes/attributes while comparing two JSONs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853598/ignore-specific-nodes-attributes-while-comparing-two-jsons)
My new statement is:

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(response2, getResponseBodyContent(), new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.LENIENT, new Customization("EffectiveEpochDate", (o1, o2) -> true)));
```

and I am getting the following errors:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:   
Groovy:expecting ')', found ',' @ line 51, column 154.  
Groovy:expecting ')', found '->' @ line 51, column 160.     
Groovy:expecting ')', found '->' @ line 51, column 160.     
Groovy:expecting '}', found '->' @ line 51, column 160.     
Groovy:expecting '}', found '->' @ line 51, column 160.
```

I am using a testing tool called Katalon that supports java/groovy. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Katalon uses groovy as language. For groovy the following expression is wrong `(o1, o2) -> true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are referencing uses the Java lambda syntax (which for sure is not supported up to and including Groovy 2.5).  You have to pass an closure instead.  E.g. turn

```java
(o1, o2) -> true
```

into:

```
{a, b -> true}
```