# How can I ignore some JSON and object properties during unit testing?

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, kotlin, junit4

I have a method that is migrating old JSON structure to a new one that I would like to test, but there is one randomly generated property (UUID) that I would like to ignore.

The interesting part of the object looks like this:

```
val expected = FooterContainer(id = UUID.fromString("11914145-9775-4675-9c65-54bbd369fb2c"), title = null, flowType=ContainerType.ROWS, elements=listOf() //the rest is not important.
```

The JSON to be converted looks totally different from this object, but this is the purpose of the method - to convert it to a new model.

```
val json = """[{"type": "list", "items": [{"link": "www.something.com", "type": "link", "label": "Some label"},
            {"type": "text", "label": "Another label"}, {"type": "text", "label": "Other label"},
            {"type": "text", "label": "yet another label"}, {"type": "text", "label": "info@something.com"}]
```

et cetera.

The below code worked as expected:

```
val gson: JsonElement = Gson().fromJson(json, JsonElement::class.java)

    // when
    val converted = with(ClientDataRepository()) {
        gson.readFooter()
    }
```

until I had to introduce a new field in `FooterContainer` object, which was `val id: UUID`

The method `readFooter()` is generating the `UUID` randomly, which is an expected behaviour.

But now, I cannot just assign a random (or hardcoded, as in the example code above) `UUID` to the expected class, which is logical - two randomly generated UUIDs will never be the same.

when I run the test, I obviously get:

```
Expected :FooterContainer(id=11914145-9775-4675-9c65-54bbd369fb2c,
Actual   :FooterContainer(id=7ba39ad0-1412-4fda-a827-0241916f8558,
```

Now, is there a possibility to ignore the `id` field for this test? It is not important from the test perspective, but the rest is.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy the `id` field from the `actual` object to the `expected`:

```kotlin
val converted = with(ClientDataRepository()) {
    gson.readFooter()
}

val expected = FooterContainer(id = converted.id, title = null, flowType=ContainerType.ROWS, elements=listOf()) //the rest is not important.
Assertions.assertThat(converted).isEqualTo(expected);
```

If you are using [assertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/), there is a stright forward solution:

```
Assertions.assertThat(converted).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(expected, "id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit). In this case you can modify your code in next way:

```
assertThatJson("{\"id\":${json-unit.ignore}}").isEqualTo("{\"id\": 11914145-9775-4675-9c65-54bbd369fb2c}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like json-assert (https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) that support ignoring keys - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328139/4473822