# Java support for json testing?

Tags: java, json, unit-testing

I am using `morphia` (ODM for `mongodb`) in my project and write its annotations on my models.
I want to write unit tests to validate the mapping.
I can call the mapper, using `morphia.getMapper().toDBObject(input)` and run a test on the output.
For example, for the model

Car:

```
@Property("COLOR")
String color;
@Property("PlaTE")
int plate;
@Property("seats")
int seats;
```

I expect to receive the output:

```
{ "COLOR" : "value", "PlaTE" : 111, "seats" : 4 }
```

In order to test it, I need to create a string that represent this output, and in java it's a nightmare...

```
String expected = "{ \"COLOR\": \"value\", \"PlaTE\": 111, \"seats\" }";
```

And you can see how ugly this can get with embedded objects and arrays...

I was thinking of writing the output in a `json` file and read it during the test, but it kinda breaks the rules of unit testing...
Is there any convenient way of representing json objects in java to achieve a neat and clean unit tests?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/compare-two-json-objects-in-java goes into various options you have.

Comment: To be more clear, I meant to an easy way to write and read (with human eyes) the json, like in JavaScript. I guess no other way than separate json file...

Comment: Well, since the answers to both (pretty similar) questions are "no", then I guess it is a duplication...

Comment: Take a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate), it has everything you are looking for and more. (disclaimer: I am the dev).

Comment: @aha IMO this is NOT a duplicate.  The reason is this question is specific to testing JSON in Java.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a way to test your RESTful endpoints (JSON or XML), I would recommend http://rest-assured.io/ I've used it in a number of projects and it's great. They have excellent documentation too: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage