# JSONObject.similar(JSONObject) what does this really compare?

Tags: java, json

I was looking for a way to compare two JSONObjects besides using

JSONObject.toString().equals(JSONObject.toString())

and came across this similar method but it's really vague about what it compares.

"Determine if two JSONObjects are similar. They must contain the same set of names which must be associated with **similar values**." [Link](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#similar-java.lang.Object-)

What is that supposed to mean? How similar? Exactly the same?

I searched really hard and couldn't find anything that could clear it up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2255893/1814524

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the [source](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/20211205/src/main/java/org/json/JSONObject.java) for `JSONObject.similar()`:

```
/**
 * Determine if two JSONObjects are similar.
 * They must contain the same set of names which must be associated with
 * similar values.
 *
 * @param other The other JSONObject
 * @return true if they are equal
 */
public boolean similar(Object other) {
    try {
        if (!(other instanceof JSONObject)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!this.keySet().equals(((JSONObject)other).keySet())) {
            return false;
        }
        for (final Entry<String,?> entry : this.entrySet()) {
            String name = entry.getKey();
            Object valueThis = entry.getValue();
            Object valueOther = ((JSONObject)other).get(name);
            if(valueThis == valueOther) {
                continue;
            }
            if(valueThis == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (valueThis instanceof JSONObject) {
                if (!((JSONObject)valueThis).similar(valueOther)) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (valueThis instanceof JSONArray) {
                if (!((JSONArray)valueThis).similar(valueOther)) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (valueThis instanceof Number && valueOther instanceof Number) {
                if (!isNumberSimilar((Number)valueThis, (Number)valueOther)) {
                    return false;
                };
            } else if (!valueThis.equals(valueOther)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Throwable exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Essentially `similar()` recursively compares the names and values of the `JSONObject`s and returns true if they're the same.
First, it checks if the `keySet`s are equal, then moves on to the values.
It recursively checks each value in the `keySet` to see if they are equal in each `JSONObject`. If not, it returns false.

Answer (score 4):

The description you found relates to method JSONObject.similar(), which compares if two JSON objects are the same, but having perhaps a different order of its attributes.

The equals() will compare each string caracter, one-by-one checking if it is the same, having the same order.

Comment: It depends on JSONObject implementation. Remember that org.json.JSONObject equals method is not overriden and it only checks if reference is same. In example new JSONObject("{}").equals(new JSONObject("{}")) would return false (for org.json.* implementation)