# How to ignore certain attributes when comparing two json files using skyscreamer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to exclude certain JSON attributes when comparing two JSON files using skyscreamer.

Test file1:

```
 {
   "Name":"test1",
   "addressList":[
      {
         "street":"123 fake street",
         "postalcode":"33344"
      },
      {
         "street":"99 street avn",
         "postalcode":"23434"
      },
      {
         "street":"900 street city",
         "postalcode":"45100"
      }
   ]
}
```

Test file2:

```
 {
   "Name":"test1",
   "addressList":[
      {
         "street":"123 fake street",
         "postalcode":"33344"
      },
      {
         "street":"88 abc street",
         "postalcode":"23434"
      },
      {
         "street":"900 street city",
         "postalcode":"45100"
      }
   ]
}
```

how to compare above JSON files by excluding addressList.street attribute?

Comment: Hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/compare-two-json-objects-in-java/2255893#2255893

Comment: thank you @AbhinavRisal, it was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use the CustomComparator and write an own custom comparator based on needs

```
 org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.Customization
 org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.comparator.CustomComparator
```

example:

```
compareJSON(expected, actual,  new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode,new Customization(addressList.street,(o1, o2) -> true)))
```