# Ignore Field in json in assert operation

Tags: java, mule, munit

I'm trying to write a MUNIT test case for mule service and want to ignore a field having timestamp. Currently, i'm using below code to perform the compare.

```
org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(getResource('json/item-locations.json').asString(), payload, false);
```

I want to ignore field "creationDateTime" which is available in my json message.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60818097/1807187

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the field from the message before comparing it. If you want to make sure it's actually there, then replace it with a constant value, but only if it exists.

Comment: No, we cannot delete the field. there needs to be some way to ignore the field while comparing.

Comment: Why can’t you delete it? Will something bad happen?