# How to perform custom JSON comparisons in a JUnit test?

Tags: java, json, junit

I have JSON objects called `Info` which have only strings & look like this :

```
{
  "prop1":      "value1",
  "prop2":      "value1",
  "timestamp":  "2018-02-28T05:30:10.100Z",
  "prop4":      "value4",
  "prop_N":     "I have a total of 10 properties."
}
```

I want to compare them with an expected JSON object.

For this, I convert expected and actual JSON into Java objects/POJO. My expected JSON can have nulls in any of the 4 properties. If any expected JSON fields are null, then I want my code to not compare those fields. If they are not null, then compare them using `String.equals()`, with one exception: for the `timestamp` which is always UTC, we have to ignore the seconds & milliseconds.

The result of the comparison will be used in a JUnit assert method to check if the actual JSON received matches the expected JSON.

I have already implemented the code as shown below. But, there are two problems:

1. It does not tell you which fields did not match (it simply returns true/false)
2. It's very ugly because of the multiple if blocks.

Can someone suggest how to fix these problems ?

```
public boolean matchesInfo(Info givenInfo) throws Exception {

    if (this.getProp1() != null) {
        boolean prop1Matching = this.getProp1().equals(givenInfo.getProp1());
        if (prop1Matching == false){return false;}
    }

    // More if blocks like this. Very long and ugly.

    // For timestamp comparison, call a custom function to strip seconds, milliseconds.
}
```

Comment: Can someone please explain the down vote ? Without an explanation I don't know if you meant to up vote or down vote, or if you did not understand the question. I see that a lot of people in SO simply down vote a lot of good/useful questions.

Comment: Seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/2253750/1426227

Answer (score 1):

Rather than deserialising JSON into an object to facilitate comparison you could use [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit) to facilitate meaningful 'JSON comparison' in your test cases.

There are some examples below which address the points made in your question ... showing meaningful responses (i.e. name the mismatched field/value), ignoring null/absent fields. There are plenty more details [in the docs](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit), including the use of custom matchers to handle this requirement: "For the timestamp which is always UTC, we have to ignore the seconds & milliseconds.".

```
@Test
public void canAssertJsonEquality() {
    String expected = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop1\": \"value1\",\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";
    String actual = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop1\": \"value1\",\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";

    JsonAssert.assertJsonEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void canAssertJsonEqualityRegardlessOfPropertyOrder() {
    String expected = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop1\": \"value1\",\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";
    String actual = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\",\n" +
            "  \"prop1\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";

    JsonAssert.assertJsonEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void canIgnoreFieldsWhichAreInActualButNotInExpected() {
    String expected = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";
    String actual = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop1\": \"value1\",\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";

    JsonAssert.assertJsonEquals(expected, actual, JsonAssert.when(Option.IGNORING_EXTRA_FIELDS));
} 

// fails with ...
//      Different keys found in node "", expected: <[prop1, prop2]> but was: <[prop2]>. Missing: "prop1"
@Test
public void willFailIfActualIsMissingAProperty() {
    String expected = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop1\": \"value1\",\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";
    String actual = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";

    JsonAssert.assertJsonEquals(expected, actual);
}

// fails with ...
//      Different value found in node "prop1", expected: <"value1"> but was: <"value2">.
@Test
public void willFailIfActualHasAnIncorrectValue() {
    String expected = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop1\": \"value1\",\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";
    String actual = "{\n" +
            "  \"prop1\": \"value2\",\n" +
            "  \"prop2\": \"value1\"\n" +
            "}";

    JsonAssert.assertJsonEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve this with ModelAssert - https://github.com/webcompere/model-assert.

Firstly, we could just assert the fields we're interested in:

```java
assertJson(actual)
   .at("/prop1").isText("value1")
   .at("/prop2").isText("value2");
```

Or, we could use an `isEqualTo` approach, marking certain paths as ignored

```java
assertJson(actual)
   .where()
     .at("/prop2").isIgnored()
     .at("/prop3").isIgnored()
   .isEqualTo(expected);
```

`assertJson` will take in `String`, `JsonNode` and even a Map/POJO, which it serializes to JSON before comparison. Similarly `isEqualTo` also allows this.

ModelAssert also supports YML and can express its assertion as a Hamcrest matcher. It explains the differences when things fail.