# Compare two json structure and get mismatch changes

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Hi I have json structure #1 and #2 as follows. I would like to compare and capture the results.

Json #1.

```
{
    "menu": {
        "id": "file",
        "popup": {
            "menuitem": {
                "menuitem-1": "sometext",
                "menuitem-2": {
                    "menuitem-2.1": "sometext",
                    "menuitem-2.2": "sometext",
                    "menuitem-2.3": {
                        "menuitem-2.3.1": "sometext"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "value": "File"
    }
}
```

Json #2

```
{
    "menu": {
        "id": "file",
        "popup": {
            "menuitem": {
                "menuitem-2.3": {
                    "menuitem-2.3.1": "sometext"
                }
                "menuitem-1": "sometext",
                "menuitem-2": {
                    "menuitem-2.1": "sometext",
                    "menuitem-2.2": "sometext"
                },
            }
        },
        "value": "File"
    }
}
```

Am expecting that  below JSON has been moved up in JSON #2. My goal here is identify any CREATE NEW / UPDATE / ADJUSTED / DELETE on JSON#2.

```
"menuitem-2.3": {
   "menuitem-2.3.1": "sometext"
}
```

Is there any Spring / Java existing framework available to achieve above?

Comment: Is it possible to create a java POJO by Jackson and then just compare 2 classes?

Comment: @dehasi yes it is

Comment: did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/compare-two-json-objects-in-java?rq=1 might solve your issue.

Comment: I've used https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-diff-utils/ in the past for finding the minimal set of INSERT/DELETE/MOVE of nodes in XML trees (which is similar to JSON). The simple approach could be to compare the formatted text output of the JSON. A real "minimal difference" is not as easy as it sounds on trees, certainly not as easy as on lists (or lines of text).

Comment: What is the difference between UPDATE and AJUSTED?

Answer (score -1):

Try using Apache drill. It is easy to install and supports querying JSON. You can then execute a minus query and get the difference.

You can also query drill using java. Apache drill has a JDBC driver for that.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use difference from org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.
Compares two Strings, and returns the portion where they differ. (More precisely, return the remainder of the second String, starting from where it's different from the first.)

For example,

```
difference("i am a machine", "i am a robot") -> "robot".
StringUtils.difference(null, null) = null
StringUtils.difference("", "") = ""
StringUtils.difference("", "abc") = "abc"
StringUtils.difference("abc", "") = ""
StringUtils.difference("abc", "abc") = ""
StringUtils.difference("ab", "abxyz") = "xyz"
StringUtils.difference("abcde", "abxyz") = "xyz"
StringUtils.difference("abcde", "xyz") = "xyz"
```

Parameters:
str1 - the first String, may be null
str2 - the second String, may be null

Comment: This answer is not relavent.