# How to automate two JSON response comparison

Tags: java, json, api, automation, rest-assured

I want to compare two json response. I have tried to store the JSON response in a pojo then compared by overiding equals method but my pojo is very large and consist of 10 classes . Is there any other way to compare

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/testing-two-json-objects-for-equality-ignoring-child-order-in-java

Comment: You can use Jackson to compare 2 JSON , see [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code snippet:

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Assert;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.filter.cookie.CookieFilter;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

Retrive JSON responses:

```
Response jsonResponseOne = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpecification).filter(cookieFilter).relaxedHTTPSValidation().when().///.then().assertThat().extract().response();

Response jsonResponseTwo = RestAssured.given().spec(requestSpecification).filter(cookieFilter).relaxedHTTPSValidation().when().///.then().assertThat().extract().response();
```

Extract both JSON responses as a string:

```
JSONObject jsonOne = new JSONObject(jsonResponseOne.getBody().asString())
JSONobject jsonTwo = new JSONObject(jsonResponseTwp.getBody().asString())
```

Compare response using Java:

```
Assert.assertEquals(jsonOne, jsonTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the differences between them, try to use [zjsonpatch](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch) library to detect the differences between two json responses.

A sample code:

`JsonNode json1= jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(jsonString1);
 JsonNode json2= jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(jsonString2);
 JsonNode patchNode = JsonDiff.asJson(json1, json2);
 String diffs = patchNode.toString();`