# How to validate Json text which is not having any property name or key?

Tags: java, json, api, rest-assured

Am new to API testing and trying to validate response in 'JSON Text' format which is not having any key or property.Please find below json and let me know how can I validate this.Am reading the same format from another file and trying to validate with response JSON.

```
  {
"path1": true,
"path2": true,
"path3": true
}
```

Am using the below code to compare the response .But it is giving {} output(empty).
I tried with response.getBody() , jsonPath(),but none of them worked.Please suggest!

```
 validateResponse(Response response, String expectedValue) {
        String value = response.asString();
            if (value.contains(expectedValue)) {
                System.out.println("Validated Successfully: " +value);
              }
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: {
"path1": true,
"path2": true,
"path3": true
}..this is expected output..which I captured from ARC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253750/testing-two-json-objects-for-equality-ignoring-child-order-in-java check this.