# TetsNG SoftAssert with Hamcrest matcher

Tags: testng, hamcrest

I want to use a Hamcrest matcher inside a TestNG test and with a soft assert specifically. How can I do this? I know that I can use Hamcrest's assertions inside a test like:

```
assertThat(actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected));
```

But I can't understand how can I use TestNG soft assert method like this one:

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
```

together with a Hamcrest matcher.

Because I can't invoke the Hamcrest's `assertThat` on TestNG's `softAssert` like `softAssert.assertThat(...)`

So, what is the correct way to use a Hamcrest matcher together with TestNG?

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot directly blend `SoftAssert` from TestNG with the hamcrest matcher assertions.

But you can make use of `org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions` within the hamcrest matcher library for trying to do soft assertions.

The [javadocs](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/SoftAssertions.html) for `SoftAssertions` has some samples.

For the sake of completeness, I am including the code snippet from the javadocs here.

```java
 @Test
 public void host_dinner_party_where_nobody_dies() {
   Mansion mansion = new Mansion();
   mansion.hostPotentiallyMurderousDinnerParty();
   SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();
   softly.assertThat(mansion.guests()).as("Living Guests").isEqualTo(7);
   softly.assertThat(mansion.kitchen()).as("Kitchen").isEqualTo("clean");
   softly.assertThat(mansion.library()).as("Library").isEqualTo("clean");
   softly.assertThat(mansion.revolverAmmo()).as("Revolver Ammo").isEqualTo(6);
   softly.assertThat(mansion.candlestick()).as("Candlestick").isEqualTo("pristine");
   softly.assertThat(mansion.colonel()).as("Colonel").isEqualTo("well kempt");
   softly.assertThat(mansion.professor()).as("Professor").isEqualTo("well kempt");
   softly.assertAll();
 }
```

If you take a look at the [SoftAssertions](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/assertj/core/api/SoftAssertions.java) codebase, you would notice that the comments say that its been inspired by Cedric's [blog](http://beust.com/weblog/2012/07/29/reinventing-assertions) on soft assertions.

Comment: Yes, I saw blog posts about AssertJ and SoftAssertions. But I can use only TestNG and Hamcrest in my project. So, I should try to use matchers built-in TestNG if I want to use SoftAssert.

Comment: Yes, `SoftAssertions` is part of the same hamcrest jar. The TestNG `SoftAssert` API doesn't give you the feel of what a hamcrest matcher gives. But both do the same thing. So if you are used to the hamcrest like APIs for your assertion, then use `SoftAssertions` to continue to get the same feel. Else you can use `SoftAssert` from TestNG.

Comment: You're probably confusing because `SoftAssertions` is not part of the Hamcrest. It is part of [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/SoftAssertions.html).